# When does my wallet reflect my baking/endorsing rewards/deposits?

Tags: baking, ledger, kiln, rewards, ledger-live

I'm using Kiln to bake and endorse with my Ledger Nano S. When I check Ledger Live, my wallet balance is the same as when I started my baker.

When I check [tzstats](https://tzstats.com/tz1ithWfkskHQeYmU4Sq8SmCdJpvJSJDn9sX) for my wallet address, I have the details of what my "full balance" is and the deposit/reward details. When will my wallet in Ledger Live reflect that balance? The transactions in Ledger Live show my deposit and reward receipts, but no amounts.

Is this a limitation of the Ledger Live software? Will it affect my ability to withdraw funds whenever the day comes that I stop baking?